# Mail Composer Won't Launch From UIPreviewAction

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, 3dtouch

In the view controller for my Peek view of an app I have:

```
- (NSArray*)previewActionItems {  

    /  
    UIPreviewAction *action1 = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Post to Facebook" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {  


    }];  

    UIPreviewAction *action2 = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Message" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {  


    }];  

    UIPreviewAction *action3 = [UIPreviewAction actionWithTitle:@"Email" style:UIPreviewActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIPreviewAction * _Nonnull action, UIViewController * _Nonnull previewViewController) {  
        [self displayComposerSheet];  


    }];  

    /  
    NSArray *actions = @[action1, action2, action3];  

    /  
    return actions;  
}
```

This successfully allows me to pull up a sheet of preview actions after a 3D Touch.  displayComposerSheet is:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet  
{  
    NSLog(@"Mail Button Pressed");
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];  
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;  

    [picker setSubject:@"Check out this article from Fritch"];  


    /  
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"friend@example.com"];  

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];  

    /  
    NSString *emailBody = self.finalObject.articleImage;  
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];  

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];  
    [picker release];  
}
```

However, the mail composer never is presented.  Please help.

Comment: What is the result of [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ?

Comment: I think we need some more information. What is the view controller hierarchy you are presenting from? Is the presenting controller pushed or is it modal as well? Is this not working on all devices, iphone only or ipad only and on all or some iOS versions?

Comment: Since this is a question about Peek and Pop, should be obvious we are talking about iOS 9 and the 6S and 6S Plus.  The hierarchy is a Navigation Controller that pushes the NewsViewController, which is a TableViewController.  From there, the hard press shows the PreviewViewController, which is what has all the code I listed, as a peek.  Sliding up shows my actions, but pressing Email does nothing, though it does fire my NSLog in the console.  @RoryMcKinnel

Comment: The issue is probably that the view hierarchy is not normal when the Peek view is shown. Try using this to present the picker: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Works great, @RoryMcKinnel!  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept and award the bounty.

Comment: Excellent. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is probably that the view hierarchy is not normal when the Peek view is shown.

Try using the root view controller to present the picker:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```